# How to get rid of black lines over and under the Search Bar?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisearchbar, searchbar

Can someone please tell me how I can get rid of the black line on bottom of the Search Bar? Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Edit:
[image]
How can I change this color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change search bar type to minimal

Comment: It went away. Thank You!

Comment: How can I make the inside color change? And I mean the inside rectangle that contains the word 'Search'.

Comment: you try to change background color of view

Comment: Yea the background color of view is what I want but the color of the smaller container of the text is a color I don't want.

Comment: Check above I added an image.

Comment: you cannot change color of textfield in search bar with minimal style, it can be a bug, change search bar style to default and custom border color of search : 
`barsearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor`